# Rails - Select tag not pre-selected after Form's validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have select tag

```
 <%= f.select :gender, ["M", "F"], include_blank: "---" %>
```

If other field has error, the select tag will be reset to "---" even though I have picked an option before.

The solution that I found is using `collection_select` which takes a ActiveRecord Model to be the option-value pair.

Is there other way to do this?

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

The answer from @Micah is correct but since my form is Nested, it's different syntax.

Here's my code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :users do |ff| %>
  ...
  <%= ff.select :gender, ["M", "F"], include_blank: "---",
        selected: ff.object.gender ? ff.object.gender : ""  %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: This sorted issue for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I handle errors I usually use `render` to display the previous page again so I'm going to explain how to handle that first.

When you render a view the params that got passed into your previous command carry over, meaning you'll have `params[:object][:gender]`as a parameter when you return to the view. Thus

```
<%= f.select :gender, ["M", "F"], include_blank: "---", selected: params[:object] ? params[:object][:gender] :"" %>
```

will set the selected value back to what was selected the first time through. Basically what it's doing is taking a conditional and then providing an if/else in the same line. `(conditional) ? if true do this : else do this`. In this case the conditional is that `params[:object]` exists (meaning you've attempted to create/edit once before) and if so reassign value otherwise leave blank and select default value, your "---".

If you use redirect_to you'll actually have to manually pass the params back through the redirect but that's fairly simple and just takes the following:

`redirect_to new_object_path(params)`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Using the conditional doesn't work, but testing with hard-coded `selected: "F"` does work. Is that the right syntax for params?

Comment: Nevermind, my form is Nested, so it's different syntax, I will put my code above for other reference

Comment: @DarcCode That is the correct format for params but it seems you had it set up a little different than I had assumed. Glad it helped out though :)